# How to use a tool installed with Python pip in a run_binary rule

Tags: bazel

In my `WORKSPACE`, I've added a dependency to the `hatch` module, which provides an executable named `hatch`. I want to use this executable as a tool in a `run_binary` rule.

`run_binary()` seems to expect a target as the `tool`, but I'm not sure how to write a rule to use a binary that was installed through `pip_parse` in the `WORKSPACE` file.

(Alternative methods to accomplish this are also appreciated.)

##### `WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "b8a1527901774180afc798aeb28c4634bdccf19c4d98e7bdd1ce79d1fe9aaad7",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.1/bazel-skylib-1.4.1.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.1/bazel-skylib-1.4.1.tar.gz",
    ]
)
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "ffc7b877c95413c82bfd5482c017edcf759a6250d8b24e82f41f3c8b8d9e287e",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.19.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.19.0/rules_python-0.19.0.tar.gz",
)

http_archive(
    name = "aspect_bazel_lib",
    sha256 = "2518c757715d4f5fc7cc7e0a68742dd1155eaafc78fb9196b8a18e13a738cea2",
    strip_prefix = "bazel-lib-1.28.0",
    url = "https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-lib/releases/download/v1.28.0/bazel-lib-v1.28.0.tar.gz",
)

# for aspect's run_binary rule
load("@aspect_bazel_lib//lib:repositories.bzl", "aspect_bazel_lib_dependencies")
aspect_bazel_lib_dependencies()

# install Python requirements
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")
pip_parse(
    name = "py_mod_deps",
    requirements_lock = "//py-mod:requirements.txt"
)
load("@py_mod_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")
install_deps()
```

##### `py-mod/requirements.txt`

```
hatch==1.6.3
# other dependencies from pip-compile requirements.in
```

##### `py-mod/BUILD`

```
load("@aspect_bazel_lib//lib:run_binary.bzl", "run_binary")

run_binary(
    name = "mymodule",
    tool = "hatch",
    args = ["build"],
    srcs = glob(["**/*.py"])
    out_dirs = ["dist/"]
)
```

This is meant to run `hatch build` to produce the Python module files under the `dist/` directory.

### Error

When I run `bazel build //py-mod:mymodule`, I get the error:

```
ERROR: .../py-mod/BUILD: RunBinary py-mod/dist failed: missing input file '//py-mod:hatch'
ERROR: .../py-mod/BUILD: RunBinary py-mod/dist failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
```

### Attempts

I thought of using [`native_binary`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/docs/native_binary_doc.md) from `bazel-skylib`, but I'm not sure what to put for `src` since I don't know where `pip_parse` puts the `hatch` executable.

```
native_binary(
    name = "hatch",
    src = "???",
    out = "//py-mod:hatch"
)
```

I also thought about just making `hatch` into a Python library so I could build it myself and just run it, but it seems there's no supported way to make a script to `import hatch` and run something like `hatch.build(args)`. *If* I could do that, I could do something like:

```
load("@py_mod_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

py_binary(
    name = "hatch",
    srcs = ["my_hatch_wrapper.py"],
    main = "my_hatch_wrapper.py",
    deps = [
        requirement("hatch")
    ]
)
```

then use this rule's output in the `tool` parameter of the `run_binary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entry_point` solves this problem.

`WORKSPACE` stays as in from the question.

##### `py-mod/BUILD`

```
load("@py_mod_deps//:requirements.bzl", "entry_point")
alias(
    name = "hatch",  # <-- now I can use hatch as a label in this package
    actual = entry_point("hatch"),
)

load("@aspect_bazel_lib//lib:run_binary.bzl", "run_binary")
run_binary(
    name = "mymodule",
    tool = "hatch",  # <-- here we're using that label
    args = ["build"],
    srcs = glob(["**/*.py"])
    out_dirs = ["dist/"]
)
```

Comment: Not a comment on the anser, more about bazel utility in general. this seems like obfuscation - The alias for apple is "apple" so that you can run the thing - who thinks up this obscura?